# Limit the height of dropdown with bootstrap-select

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-selectpicker

How do you limit how many options are included in a select? I have around 2000 options (I am using data-live-search to make it easy to search), but I don't want to make an extremely long list (for aesthetic purposes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently spent an hour trying to find how to restrict the height of a dropdown. Turns out the size attribute for select tags is set to `'auto'` in the javascript file. For me, it was around line 369.

The solution is simple:

Set `size: '8'` or however many options you want to be listed

Comment: data-size="8" in hmtl select element works for me, it displays only 8 (or n) entries in the dropdown and can be scrolled or filtered to show others

Answer (score 1):

`size` and `data-size` didn't work for me. I need to override CSS with this:

```
div.dropdown-menu.open{
  max-height: 314px !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.dropdown-menu.inner{
  max-height: 260px !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Change the size as you like.